Android Beta 15, leaving the beta program without wipe
I have Android Beta 15 (AP41.240925.009).
Is it possible to leave the beta program without wiping?
I tried opting out from the beta program, but then received an update that said it will wipe the device.
When I opt back in, I get an update for Android 15 QPR2 Beta 1.
That update clearly says

If you are currently running a Beta version of Android 15 QPR1 (build starting with AP41) and want to exit the beta program without wiping your device, you can opt out of the Beta program before applying this update

But that doesn't seem to be the case:


Is it possible to leave the beta program without wiping? No, it isn't.

I was in A15 beta and left. Then an A14 (stable) update showed (as this was before stable A15 came out), so I ignored and did wait until A15 (stable) came out.  A15 stable then replaced the the beta update that was showing as an update.  So maybe try and leave the beta and wait to see if A15 stable eventually shows up. Then you can update w/o a wipe. Make sure you are rebooting your phone also periodically.
With that said, I believe once you go QPR, you cannot exit without a wipe, which I believe this link confirms (see the second bullet): https://www.androidauthority.com/p-3471654/

If you don't want to continue beta testing and opt out without data wipe. It's always the same for all beta versions of Android. You just opt out and ignore the updates with data wipe until you are offered a stable update without a data wipe.
The information above regarding qpr exit is false, you can opt out without data wipe from all beta versions in the opt out period which for qpr 1 is this month:
If you have installed the QPR1 Beta 1 update, you’ll have to wait until December for the next opportunity to leave the program without having to wipe your data.

It would be nice to have a reference for this.
